# Overwrite branch with changes from another branch

Tags: git, github, merge

Hello fellow git users!

I am having the following problem and I don't know what would be the best and correct way to avoid it. So here I will explain:

I am working with 2 different branches:

- `master` --> production
- `dev` --> development

The workflow I am currently using is the following:

1. Changes are made on `dev` branch
2. Changes are tested and approved
3. Checkout `master` and merge `dev` to include new changes

Nothing crazy so far, right?

Now, the following scenario appeared a few weeks ago:

1. Changes are made on `dev` branch
2. Changes are tested and approved
3. Checkout `master` and merge `dev` to include new changes
4. Someone realized part of those changes should not be in `master` (production)
5. In `master` branch **we commented** those changes so that those are not enabled in `master`

Current situation:

- All changes are in `dev`
- All changes are in `master` but part of them are disabled
- So far so good

A few days later, the following happened:

1. A few more changes were added to `dev`
2. Changes were tested and approved
3. Checkout `master` and merge `dev` to include recent new changes and **also** part of the change that is now commented in `master`.
4. As a result, everything is included in `master` **but** the change that had been commented is **still commented** in `master`.

At the beginning, I was kind of expecting `master` to be overwritten with the `dev` version but then I realised that does not make much sense as merging is actually putting together changes from both branches so the result is making absolute sense. However, it is not what I need.

What would be the best solution for this? I was thinking about the following options:

1. To absolutely prohibit making changes in `master` branch. So any change (like commenting part of the code) should be done first in `dev` and then go to `master`.
2. When merging into `master` to use a parameter saying *ignore all changes in the current branch and just take all that is coming from `dev` branch*. That would be awesome and obviously I don't know how to do it in git.

Anyway, your comments will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read up on GitFlow, at [Vincent Driessen's original blog about it](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).

What's missing here is that you made commits directly to `master`. Never do that! :)

You have a few options, depending on your exact situation, but if you are following GitFlow, here would be the answer:

1. When ready for a release, make a `release_xxx` branch, which is essentially a release candidate for a new version.
2. Use the release branch during integration and system testing with other repos/code, etc.
3. If a change is required, make it to `release`, but then merge that change to `dev` as well.
4. When `release` is fully tested, merge it into master, ending it.

If you don't normally need any extended time for a release branch, you can create a `hotfix` branch, which, after testing, would be merged both to `master` and `dev`. Hotfix branches are normally for production problems from something already released into production - it's like a feature branch that merges into `dev`, except intended to merge directly back to `master` (in addition to `dev` so all the development branches get the change as well).

This allows you to continue with other parallel development in `dev` without having to push new things put in `dev` to `master`, leaving just the changes needed for the fix to happen in a `release` or `hotfix` branch, and you can manage pushing that back to `dev` separately to make sure it incorporates with any parallel work.

[image]

Credit: [Vincent Driessen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpnXK.png)

---

### To resolve the current issue

You should reverse-merge `master` into `dev`, resolve all differences (i.e. add or remove comments, etc.), and then merge back to `master`. If you just want to cleanup, you can do so and direct push to master, but it's better to have a PR with review of peers in `dev` to give traceability and shows clearly what was done in the git history.

Answer (score 1):

#### This is what you should have done

You should have merged your `master` into `dev` (a sort of hotfix, which are fine) right after you made the changes to `master`.

Then on `dev` you should have reverted **the commit** (`git revert commit-id`) which commented out things in `master`.

Then when you went on to merge `dev` into `master` again, things would be fine.

#### Now that things have gone further you can:

1. [BEST APPROACH] try those steps above; if changes made in `dev` aren't deep enough and/or don't touch the same places as **the commit**, chances are the all is going to be right; or
2. in `master` branch go on to revert (`git revert`) **the commit**.